# Grub Customizer taking over 5 minutes to start

Tags: grub2

Since updating 12.04 to 12.10, the Grub Customizer now takes over 5 minutes to appear on screen after clicking on icon. I have tried reinstalling it. Any other suggestions as 5 minutes+ seems far too long to wait.

Answer (score 0):

My Grub Customizer was working normally on my 64bit 12.10, previously.
Now though after a few un-related updates, it changed to the 5 minutes later behaviour - as above.

So with a bit of **lateral thinking** I decided to delve into the **BIOS**.

I had recently updated the BIOS to fit a PCIe x16 graphics card.
This had in turn removed the MAIN section option which DISABLES the Legacy Floppy Drive!

*So the delay is due to a fruitless search for the non-existent floppy drive.*

**Change your BIOS Legacy Floppy Drive Option to DISABLE**